# On delete postgres trigger with fkey

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgres to create a table that has an fkey to itself

```
create table "public"."notes" (
  "id" serial not null,

  "body" text,
  "link" int4,

  primary key (id),
  constraint "link_key" foreign key (link) references notes(id) on update cascade
);

create or replace function notes_unlink() returns trigger as
  $$
    begin
      update notes set link = null where link = old.id; -- satisfy fkey constraint
      return new;
    end;
  $$
language plpgsql;

create trigger notes_unlink_trigger before delete on notes
for each row execute procedure notes_unlink();
```

I want to have an on delete trigger that sets "linked" notes to null so the delete can occur. I.e.

```
insert into notes (body, link) values ('foo',null); -- assume id here is 1
insert into notes (body, link) values ('bar',1);
select * from notes;
 id | body | link |
----+------+------+
  1 | foo  |      |
  2 | bar  |    1 |
```

On an attempted delete like `delete from notes where id = 1;` I'd like the trigger to set note 2.link to null and the delete to succeed. I've tried *a lot* of rules and triggers and so on, no luck. What currently happens is that the delete doesn't delete anything at all (0 records output), even on a note that is not linked.

Comment: What's wrong with just using the built-in `ON DELETE SET NULL` option? That trigger seems superfluous.

Comment: To make that trigger work (although it's unnecessary) you need to assign the value to the new record, not run an UPDATE: `new.link := null;`

Comment: thanks that's very helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ON DELETE SET NULL` when you create the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE notes
ADD CONSTRAINT link_key
    FOREIGN KEY (link) REFERENCES notes (id)
       ON UPDATE CASCADE
       ON DELETE SET NULL;
```